# How do I find the value of this summation problem involving exponents?

Tags: summation, exponentiation

I've looked around online quite a bit and still can't figure out exactly what to do here.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

$\sum _{j=0}^4 (-2)^j = (-2)^0+(-2)^1+(-2)^2+(-2)^3+(-2)^4 = 1+ (-2)+4+(-8)+16 = 11$